# Optimize dataframe pyspark before download in CSV

Tags: csv, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, download

I work with pyspark and at the end of my script. I need to download data in CSV. But I have timeout error. I have many data(4Go)
If you have commands to optimize and save the data.
If you told to me you need to create a new dataframe and you put the old one in, I tried but it's not working.
Without Pandas please.
I need à big help
Thank you

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for timeout error. It can be either connection issue or data size. First confirm if you can read a minimised version of your data. This will rule out connection issue. Please post minimum woking example with sample dataset as text. Also provide details about infrastructure you are using.

Comment: Hi, the error is to use persist(). I create many dataframes. My DAG very saturated and I had the error with performances